# WordPress Plugin - Checkbox Undefined Index if not checked

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a checkbox and if is not checked it shows "undefined index"
I have searched here I found some similar answers but I couldn't make it work.

Here is the way I print the checkbox input

```
printf(
        '<input type="checkbox" id="custom_conversion_enable" name="conversion_settings_option_custom[custom_conversion_enable]" value="1" '. checked( 1, $this->options_custom['custom_conversion_enable'], false ) .' />',
              isset( $this->options_custom['custom_conversion_enable'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options_custom['custom_conversion_enable']) : ''


       );
```

Comment: Are you using this inside something? I guess from: `conversion_settings_option_custom[custom_conversion_enable]` Because the checkbox seems to have every attributes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Key is a string, need to send it back to php as a string.

```
name="conversion_settings_option_custom['custom_conversion_enable']"
```